# There is insufficient space on the device

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, installation, storage

My phone is rooted and I have android terminal installed. How can I fix this " There is insufficient space on the device" when installing from Google play. However when I install from Apk file it works fine and gets installed.

Comment: Which app and which version

Comment: Any app,  I get this error,